# Which is the best `useReducer` -> reducer function declaration

Tags: reactjs, optimization, coding-style, react-hooks

Looking at the [react doc](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), there is an initial way to do it. But like many others, it's rarely the efficient way.

So, I wonder which is the best / efficient / cleaner way to declare the `reducer` function since it's a [pure function](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_pure) :

> assume `import React, { useReducer, useCallback } from 'react'`

## 1. External function (doc style)

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => state
const MyComp = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {})
}
```

## 2. `useCallback` declaration

```js
const MyComp = () => {
  const reducer = useCallback((state, action) => state, [])
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {})
}
```

## 3. `useCallback` inline declaration alternative

```js
const MyComp = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(useCallback((state, action) => state, []), {})
}
```

## 4. inline function declaration

```js
const MyComp = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer((state, action) => state, {})
}
```

> Note: readability is a concern of course but I don't need this argument here :)

All this ways "works" and I can't see overly function re-declaration. But I wonder why not the react documentation not describe the `2. useCallback` way that if find it cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the first approach.

It's the simplest and it's very unlikely you run into any perf issues.

React core team themselves warn against **premature optimization**. using `useCallback` where it's not needed is a premature optimization and add unnecessary complexity.

About inline functions: I (and many devs I know) don't approve of inline functions like (approach 3 or 4). it's not a big deal but it's not **"clean"**.

Comment: Following your *premature optimization* argument, I fall in the lecture of this article sounds very interesting : https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578

Comment: @HollyPony Yes. being nit-picky about perf details like inline functions is also an instance of premature optimization. What I said above about inline functions was code-style wise. Hope I've answered your question!